# Синтаксическая ошибка в запросе к MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать правильно?

```
     $result = mysql_query(SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int, id_school FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_parent' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_school IN ('$id_school', '$id_school1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно строку с SQL-запросом взять в кавычки

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname, class_str, class_int, id_school FROM datacenter WHERE surname = '$surname_parent' AND type = 'scholar' AND id_school IN ('$id_school', '$id_school1')");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Как сделать правильно?

Правильно использовать нормальную среду разработки [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) или любую другую. Это вас избавит от такого рода глупых ошибок..

Comment: а зачем IDE сразу? Тут проблема мозга и(или) неопытности а не того в чем пишет ТС

Comment: Видимо это вы заминусовали )
Ну что ж.. отвечу. 
IDE подсвечивает синтаксические ошибки и возможно автор обратит на это внимание прежде чем постить вопрос сюда. 
Мозг и опытность это конечно правильно.. по почему бы не посоветовать человеку с самого начала двигаться в нужном направлении ? Что и было сделанно ;)

Comment: Нет я не минусовал, с чего вы взяли что IDE "нужное направление"?

Если автор пишет на PHP то он уже в не том направлении ^.^ впрочем как и я, да и вы, как я понимаю, тоже...

PHP не тот язык где не обойтись без IDE, я под linux'ом успешно писал и пишу php( javascript, html, java, c++ ) коди в простом и очень легком редакторе medit где кроме подсветки и терминала ничего нет.

И как-бы таких ошибок не возникает ^.^

Comment: IDE, в целом, не обязательно, а вот наличие подсветки синтаксиса в редакторе точно решило бы вопрос на месте...

Comment: Перешел с редакторов на IDE когда начал работать на больших проектах
(до этого тоже кричал во все горло что оно нафиг не нужно :))
К вашему большому удивлению, и на PHP пишут серьезные большие проекты..

Comment: Я кагбы вкурсе, но то что на нем пишут большие проекты не означает что это хороший язык...

Лично я никогда не сталкивался с php проектами с которыми мне было бы неудобно работать в простых редакторах...

я не кричу во все горло, мне не нравится юзать IDE, я никомго ни к чему не призываю, просто хотел уточнить что проблема тут никак не в IDE

Answer (score 0):

вы, всего-то, не закрыли скобку функции **mysql_query**

И да - надо взять всю строку в кавычки :)